# C shared memory with open

Tags: c

I am reading a bug fix in an OpenSource project. There was a fix related with enabling larger shared memory region. I don't understand this fix here. Could anyone explain what's the difference between those two statements?

```
Old: if (-1 == (buf->id = open(buf->seg_name, O_CREAT | O_RDWR, 0600))) {
New: if (-1 == (buf->id = open(buf->seg_name, O_RDWR))) {
```

Thanks!

Please let me know if you need more info.

Comment: What has become of the fine art of reading the [open(2) manual page](https://www.freebsd.org/cgi/man.cgi?query=open&apropos=0&sektion=2&manpath=FreeBSD+10.1-RELEASE&arch=default&format=html)?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The new code will insist on the file named by `buff->seg_name` to exist, while the old code (attempts to) create it with permission 0600 if it doesn't.